# How to load only markers that's currently visible on the screen (Google maps on Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Using Google Maps on Android does anyone have any ideas on how to load only markers that would be displayed on the current screen?

I'm thinking about sending a request to a web service that returns the lat/lng for the relevant markers. But what would the parameters be that I could use to calculate if a given lat/lng is within the screen?

What would be perfect would be something like [Gowalla's implementation](http://gowalla.com/api/explorer#/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50)

Any ideas?

Mike

Comment: what's the data source for your markers? you have your own database or you want to fetch the public markers on google maps?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long time-no-answer. I will have my own database with coordinates that I will load the application with.

Comment: I can't believe that in the past 6 years this problem has not been addressed more elloquently by google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an app that needs to do some similar things, here is my suggestion (my app is SDK Level 7)

In my example below, mapView is an object of type MapView

```
mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
```

**Returns:**
The current latitude span (from the top edge to the bottom edge of the map) in decimal degrees multiplied by one million.

and

```
mapView.getLongitudeSpan();
```

**Returns:**
The current longitude span (from the left edge to the right edge of the map) in decimal degrees multiplied by one million.

Here are another three helpful methods.

```
mapView.getLocationInWindow(location);
mapView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
mapView.getZoomLevel();
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding to your answer. I haven't been working on this map-project for some time but I'm finally getting some more time on my hands. I'll comment/accept your answer when I've tried it.

Comment: the code that you have written will only be executed once the map is scrolled. how to capture the onscroll event of the map?

Comment: This is an excellent tutorial for adding an event listener to your map and updating every time there is a scroll or zoom.  http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/2011/10/31/extending-mapview-to-add-a-change-event/